# officeHome doesn't exist or is not a directory

Tags: java, exception, plone, openoffice.org, documentviewer

I've installed document-viewer on Plone. 
When I upoad a document I receive this error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalStateException: officeHome doesn't exist or is not a directory: 
    at org.artofsolving.jodconverter.office.DefaultOfficeManagerConfiguration.buildOfficeManager(DefaultOfficeManagerConfiguration.java:165)
    at org.artofsolving.jodconverter.cli.Convert.main(Convert.java:111)
```

My openoffice installation is in /opt/openoffice4
I'm using docsplit v 0.6.4

how can I solve this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As I've read on JODConverter configuration [here](http://docs.exoplatform.com/public/index.jsp?topic=/PLF40/PLFAdminGuide.Configuration.JODConverter.html),

```
"/opt/openoffice.org3"
"/opt/libreoffice"
"/usr/lib/openoffice"
"/usr/lib/libreoffice"
```

so, I've created a symbolic link:

```
ln -s <path OpenOffice installation> <path required>
```

solved.

Comment: I am using ubuntu and "/usr/lib/libreoffice"  worked for me.

Comment: For RHEL "/opt/libreoffice6.3" works.
6.3 is installed libreoffice version